# Error to use deflater on several inputs

Tags: java, encoding, compression

I am trying to use the Deflater class to encode a textfile. The difficulty is I do not want to encode the whole textfile, but just a substring on each line. My textfile looks like this :

ELEMENT (1): {dataToEncode} 
ELEMENT (2): {dataToEncode}

I want to return a HashMap which key is the element ID (Integer) and which value is the compressed bytes corresponding to the part of the line into brackets. I would like to use the same dictionary (not preset) for all the lines since their contents are really close. Furthermore, eventually, the algorithm will have to work on the stream i.e. new lines will be written in the input textfile and should be compressed right after they are added.

I have a version that works if I reset the deflater but I think it resets also the dictionary after every line encoded, which is not as effective as keeping the same dictionary all along since annotations on the elements are quite alike.

```
    public static HashMap< Integer, byte[]> encoding(String textfile) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    HashMap< Integer, byte[]> elements = new HashMap< Integer, byte[]>();
    Deflater compresser = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
    File file = new File(textfile + ".txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String toCompress = sc.nextLine();
            
        if (toCompress.substring(0, 7).equals("ELEMENT")) {
            String infoToCompress = toCompress.substring(toCompress.indexOf('{') + 1, toCompress.indexOf('}'));
            byte [] input = infoToCompress.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte [] output = new byte[input.length + 100];
            compresser.setInput(input);
            compresser.finish();
            int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);              
            Integer element = Integer.parseInt(toCompress.substring(toCompress.indexOf('(')+1, toCompress.indexOf(")")));
            elements.put(element, output);;
            compresser.reset();
        }
    }
    compresser.end();
    sc.close();
    return elements;
}
```

If I do not use compresser.reset(), only the first element is compressed and then it compiles but does not have the expected result. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
compresser.finish();
```

It's because you're calling `finish()`. Remove.